# Can you help me read this Hebrew text?

Tags: hebrew

I need to read the text in the picture below. I know it's from the Old Testament, but I can't read the characters correctly. It would be nice if someone can help out with this.

[image: text with Hebrew characters]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

לַכֹּל זְמָן וְעֵת לְכָל־חֵפֶץ תַּחַת הַשָּׁמָֽיִם

To every thing there is a season, and a time to every purpose under the heaven: (Ecc 3:1,KJV)

Comment: Great! Thanks David

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. The verse is Qoeleth (Ecclesiastes) 3:1.